# flutter - I need to call a function when I receive local notifications

Tags: android, flutter, background, flutter-dependencies, localnotification

I am trying to execute some code (a function) whenever I receive a minutely repeated local notification on android to mimic background tasks. (I want to track our employees when the app is in background, but without using background task packages)

So, simply I am doing a trick, and I don't know whether that works or not, but what I am trying to do is, I want to periodically send local notifications to myself, using **flutter_local_notifications **package, and I want to know if there is any way that I can execute some code when I receive the notification. (the local notification act as a background task and I want to do something when I get this local notification, to mimic using background tasks.)

I have tried a lot of packages for background tasks.
Including alarm_manager_plus, background_location, and work_manager package.
the best one was workmanager package, but the frequency of repeating the background task was 15 minutes, which is far more than I want.
So, this trick came to my mind, if it works.

So, I thought if sending the scheduled local notifications for every minute and executing some code when I receive them works, then I will go with this approach.

So, I am asking, is there any way to execute some code when receiving local notification?
or is there a better way of doing that?

Any Help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Please include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). 

Are your users going to be okay with receiving notifications every minute? 

How will a user disallowing notifications affect the process you're working on?

Notificiations are not an ideal replacement for background tasks.

Comment: @daddygames My intention is to get the local notification, without showing it to the users, but when the notifications arrive, I want to run a function, instead of showing the notification to the user.
and the users will be okay if there is a background task running on their mobile, because they are our employees and we want to track their locations as they know.

Comment: try this package : https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager

you cant execute function by local notification.

Comment: @YassinRassul You cannot silently use local notifications. If the user turns them off, then your background code will not execute. 

-@pmatatias you can 100% execute any code you want when a local notification is received - within the limits of what the OS allows a notification to do.